# How to retain stacktrace when you must return a value?

Tags: python, django

For a web app, I have a method `get_stuff_for_payment` that raises `PermissionDenied` for which Django generates a `HTTP 403` to the user.

I am now asked to show a friendly error page instead of the generic 403. The following code does it. But how do I retain the stacktrace when I do this?

```
    try:
        stuff = get_stuff_for_payment(id)
    except PermissionDenied:
        return render(request, 'friendly_error_page.html', context)
```

Comment: What do you mean, "retain" the stacktrace? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Only for logging, actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to log it, then do so. The [`logging.exception`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.exception) method will log a message and append a traceback automatically:

```
except PermissionDenied as err:
    logger.exception('Permission was denied: %s', err)
```

Answer (score 0):

**StackTrace of Errors on our custom Template in python**

```
except PermissionDenied:
        return render(request, 'friendly_error_page.html', context)
```

*is not a good way in django gor dealing with 403 , 4xx or 5xx errors.*

*If we want to show exceptions which are generated , on ur template(403.html) then we could write your own 403 view, grabbing the exception and passing it to your 403 template.*

### Steps:

### #.In views.py:

```
 import sys,traceback

    def custom_403(request):
    t = loader.get_template('403.html')
    logger.info("custom msg",sys.exc_info()) // for traceback
    type, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
    return HttpResponseServerError(t.render(Context({
    'exception_value': value,
    'value':type,
    'tb':traceback.format_exception(type, value,
                                          tb)
},RequestContext(request))))
```

### #.In Main Urls.py:

```
 from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
    handler403 = 'Project.web.services.views.custom_403'
```

and if you want to show stacktrace to user use this template otherwise your custom template

### #.In Template(403.html):

```
{{ exception_value }}{{value}}{{tb}}
```